# Get file information from System.Web.HttpInputStream

Tags: c#, .net, file, casting, stream

I have code:

```
    public Upload.UploadResponse Post(Upload.UploadRequest request)
    {

        Stream str = request.RequestStream; // RequestStream is System.Web.HttpInputStream
        byte[] result;
        using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
        {
            str.CopyTo(streamReader);
            result = streamReader.ToArray();
        }
        return new Upload.UploadResponse() { Successed = 1 };
    }
```

Is there any way to get file name ( with extension) from MemoryStream or stream or System.Web.HttpInputStream (part of Upload.UploadRequest request) without saving the file? I need to recognize the file without knowing what is sent to me. I've tried to cast it to FileStream but it was null. Service framework that I am using is service stack [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/)

edit: Maybe I need to send file info with request?

p.s sorry for my poor English any corrections are welcome

EDIT:

this is UploadClass that I am using for code above

```
public class Upload
{

    [Route("/upload")]
    public class UploadRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        public System.IO.Stream RequestStream { set; get; }

    }

    public class UploadResponse
    {
        public int Successed { set; get; }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Upload.UploadRequest` look like? is it your class? how is it instanciated? is the upload coming from a browser or from somewhere else? No, filename with extension will not be in your input stream unless you put it there yourself (that is, you coded the client, or provided such instructions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extract file name from stream.

You need to add FileName property to your request.